# Linear algebra or trigonometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Im currently learning game development but math is preventing me to go farther. So i decided to take a course in khan academy. But im kinda confuse, Should i take trigonometry first or the linear algebra? Im a little slow learner so they will take some time thats why i want to know what should i take first? I had a trigo subject back then but havent applied it to any programming before so i forgot it. Now i want to start new again. There are many code on the net to solve problems in game dev especially in math problems but i want to learn and understand it. SO can someone guide me? Thanks

Comment: OMG it has alread been answered :D why put on hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear algebra is usually taken up by math and science majors on their junior or senior years. Meanwhile trigonometry can be taught in high school. You can re-learn your trigonometry first, then take a more serious linear algebra course.